# Why my zsh completion is not sourcing it?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I try to setup my zsh-completions. I also use oh-my-zsh .

A lot of shell commands provide a `some_command completion zsh`

and they often suggest sourcing it directly in `.zshrc` like so:

```sh
 source <(kubeone completion zsh)
 source <(tilt completion zsh)
 source <(civo completion zsh)
```

I can't get it working. Only when I output the command into a file `echo "$(kubeone completion zsh)" > ~/.dotfiles/completions/_kubeone`.

(That `~/.dotfiles/completions/`-path is in my `fpath`):

```sh
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)
fpath=(~/.dotfiles/completions $fpath)
```

But that approach is not that neat. I wanna make the use of adding

`source $(my_command completion zsh)` to my `.zsh_rc` file.

Interestingly SOME commands are working with that approach: like: `source <(kompose completion zsh)` but `source <(kubeone completion zsh)` wont???

Here is an excerpt from my `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ -f ~/.dotfiles/fubectl.source ] && source ~/.dotfiles/fubectl.source

export ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
export DOTFILES=$HOME/.dotfiles
export ZSH=$DOTFILES/oh-my-zsh

BUNDLED_COMMANDS=(rubocop)
UNBUNDLED_COMMANDS=(berks foreman mailcatcher rails ruby spin rubocop)
plugins=(zsh-completions zsh-autosuggestions docker fzf bundler brew cask capistrano codeclimate coffee dotenv gem git github grunt helm heroku history iterm2 minikube node redis-cli redis-cli rails rake rake-fast ruby rbenv textmate macos pod zeus terraform)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

complete -o nospace -C /usr/local/bin/terraform terraform

# load autocomplete
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)
fpath=(~/.dotfiles/completions $fpath)
autoload -U compinit && compinit

source <(kompose completion zsh) # WORKS
source <(kubeone completion zsh) # DONT WORK
```

(`kompose a→tab` WORKS)

`kubeone a→tab` returns only my folder structure

```sh
❯ kubeone completion zsh
Application\ Support/          MAMP/                     VirtualBox\ VMs/               oh-my-zsh
Applications/                  Movies/                        Wine\ Files/                   output.json
Coding/                        Music/                         builds/
...
..
.
```

but should return:

```sh
❯ kubeone apply
apply       -- Reconcile the cluster
completion  -- Generates completion scripts for bash and zsh
config      -- Commands for working with the KubeOneCluster configuration manifests
document    -- Generates documentation
help        -- Help about any command
install     -- Install Kubernetes
...
..
.
```

**What I tried so far:**

- after opening terminal `rm ~/.zcompdump*`, then tried command, then reopened terminal and tried command again.
- `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i` with different arguments

I think there is some misconfiguration or maybe a `brew` formula is disturbing?

Here is the complete output of my `brew list` command, as well my complete `.zshrc` file:  https://gist.github.com/exocode/79c9acfad9828b73d05d2abfa39f1724

Comment: Redirecting the completion into a file that is then autoloaded is a far neater solution. No need to run a dozen commands every time you start a new shell. If you want them guaranteed up-to-date, create a small function which does eval on the output and calls it.